# Htaccess redirect only one particular image to a webpage

Tags: .htaccess

I need a little help in redirecting the following through htacess,
http://www.sitename.com/uploads/images/May2014//537fccb2c3087.jpg
to
http://www.sitename.com/media/endangered-tree-kangaroo

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `/upload/images/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload/images/

RewriteRule ^May2014/537fccb2c3087\.jpg$ /media/endangered-tree-kangaroo [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks dear.
But somehow, its redirecting me to the home page, rather than the link

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: Also tell me if there are other rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: I created a new htaccess file in the /uploads/images folder.

Comment: ok what happens when you directly enter `http://www.sitename.com/media/endangered-tree-kangaroo` in your browser?

Comment: Yes but what web page (what URL)? Does it remain `http://www.sitename.com/media/endangered-tree-kangaroo`?

Comment: it works now, i don't knw what went wrong earlier. thanks a ton, The same code works now